# How to filter out messages from hbc twitter?

Tags: java, filter, twitter-hbc

1. I have tried Sample Streaming API and would like to get tweets that are only created and would like to ignore the tweets that are deleted. I have tried the filter level to be Medium to get more created messages but the result include a lot of deleted tweets.

   `endpoint.filterLevel(FilterLevel.Medium);`

Is there any filter for filtering out created messages in hbc twitter? For now, I created the function that checks if the twitter message is started with deleted, however, I wonder there should be other ways to do it.

2. I would like to get tweets only in English and I add the language en to the endpoint. However, it doesn't stop including other languages.

   ```
   List<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
   languages.add("en");
   endpoint.language(languages);
   ```